# Fast way to parse arguments from string in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, string, parsing, arguments

I want to call a function via a string such as the following:

`const inputStr = "myFunc foo=bar arg2=123 arg1=baz";`

so I can parse this and pass the parameters to my function `myFunc({arg1:"baz", arg2: 123, foo: "bar"})`

I did this several ways, mostly like this:

```
const params = {};
const strings = inputStr.split(" ");
strings.forEach((item)=>{
    const members = item.split("=");
    params[members[0]] = members[1];
})
myFunc(params)
```

I know this does not do input validation, and passes `"123"` instead of a number, but that could be `myFunc`'s job, what I really need is a shorter, hopefully a one-liner way to achieve this.

Another way could be ask the user to input a valid JSON string and just do `JSON.parse(input)` but that is much harder to type than the original example.

Any help would be appreciated.

**P.S.:** For my use case, parsing only strings (maybe numbers) is enough, but maybe for a future user, a solution that also parses sub-objects could be helpful.

Thanks!

Comment: You might be able to use [`URLSearchParams`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams) if you replace the spaces with `&`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are just looking to split the arguments and create an object, using [`Object.fromEntries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries) would work.

```js
const input = "myFunc foo=bar arg2=123 arg1=baz";

let [func, ...args] = input.split(' ');
args = Object.fromEntries(args.map(arg => arg.split('=')));

console.log(args);
```

Automatically converting to a number/boolean type would obviously require extra effort, and if you're dealing with sub-objects, you'd first need to define the syntax that you would want to use for that in your input string. Arguably, you'd be better off using JSON in that case.

Comment: I was thinking of something like `"myFunc arg1={subArg1=bar}"` but you are probably right, it's not much easier than typing JSON :) Thanks for the help!